# Android ListView item highlight programmatically

Tags: android, listview, highlight, listviewitem

I know it's been asked around but I haven't found quite the answer yet (new to Android so sorry about the ignorance)

my app's launch Activity has an EditText (called searchbox) , a ListView (designations) and a Spinner (types)

I use the EditText as a searchbox, I have to pass the string through a custom editing to make searching more flexible. After that I match that against the closest approximation I find in 'designations' and do

```
designations.setSelection(j);
```

As expected, this sets the desired item to the top of designations. But I can't find a way to highlight it via code.

NOW, i do know that if the device is in touch mode the highlighting of a selected item won't occur. So the last 4 lines of my searchbox's onTextChanged event are:

```
        designations.setFocusable(true);            
        designations.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        if (match==true)      designations.setSelection(j);
        if (st.length()==0)   designations.setSelection(0);
```

to no avail.

now, i don't have any code on searchbox's afterTextChanged(Editable s);

so could anyone give me a clue on this?

regards
~dh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out requestFocus() and maybe requestChildFocus()

Comment: thanks jq, that worked (just by using requestFocus()).

However, after reading this:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html

I don't think I will be implementing the highlighting at all

Thanks though, one more thing learned today

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the actual `View` to be selected?

```
designations.setSelection(j);
designations.getSelectedView().setSelected(true);
```