# Alternative to ListView smoothScrollToPosition()?

Tags: android

I have a ListView that potentially can have hundreds of entries.   When a selection is made I've been using a smoothScrollToPosition, thusly:

```
if (lv != null) { //Are we created yet?
    lv.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            lv.smoothScrollToPosition(k);  
        }
    });
}
```

but my users have told me they don't like the scrolling animation and would prefer to just instantly go there.   So I replaced my smooth scroll with

```
lv.setSelection(k);
```

... and now it does nothing at all.   FWIW this is all happening right after a  **notifyDatasetChanged**

In searching for a solution I came across this discussion on http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6741  which implies this is a known problem.   Is there a workaround or am I just doing this wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of setSelection says that it only scrolls to the selected position when the ListView is in touch mode. Maybe ListView is no more in touch mode once the data set has changed or maybe setSelection is simply forgotten for the next UI update cycle.

I guess you could try a workaround by calling setSelection with a delay. You could use the postDelayed method with a delay of 100 milliseconds for example. Or you could extend ListView and override layoutChildren or something related that probably gets called when the data set changes in order to re-calculate the list view item measurements. At that point it should be safe to call setSelection and you don't need to rely on guesstimating a delay.

Comment: Interesting -  doing a postDelayed makes it "scroll", or at least reposition itself properly, but it doesn't highlight the selected item like smoothScrollToPosition()!  And I'm uncomfortable relying on an arbitrary delay.I agree I could override ListView but this seems like something ListView should do natively and that's a lot of work for a minor problem.   I just want to position the highlighted selection without the smooth scrolling part.

Comment: @user316117 I agree with you, I also wouldn't want to rely on that delay. But for debugging purposes it can give you an idea what the problem might be and how to approach it. The documentation of setSelection also says that it does not select the item while in touch mode. It just scrolls to the selected position. I just read on a related question that you need to call requestFocus() or requestChildFocus() for highlighting the selected item: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428184/android-listview-item-highlight-programmatically