# Highlight the last inserted row for one second after Insert in Listview [android]

Tags: android, listview, highlight, selecteditem, listitem

My activity contains one ListView and one Floating button.
After add the new ListItem, i want to highlight the LastAdded listrow for one second.
I tried to put

```
ListView.setSelection(position);
```

method,
doesn't work.
How to Archive this goal?

Comment: You might find a good answer here : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428184/android-listview-item-highlight-programmatically?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for response, I will try.